# How to configure a windows account to save files only to a specific folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

How to configure a windows account such that the user is restricted to save/create files only to a particular folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I can think of is changing the save locations as so.

Click to save or save a file this will appear.

[image]

Now click the default locations.

[image]

After you do this you would need to lock the user from making changes.

You can use Group Policy to prevent stuff being on or saved on the desktop.

**User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Hide and Disable All Items on the Desktop**

The best thing to keep the user from being able to save to other folders which could be a lot of work would to be to make them a standard user and block "Write" and only allow "Read".

These are only some ideas to help lead to a possible answer. I will update my answer accordingly to new information.

**EDIT:**

You can use Calcs. To block Write access or read access to certain folders or sub folders. Usage as follows.

> filename Displays ACLs of specified directory, file or files.
>
> /t Changes ACLs of specified files in the current directory and all 
>   subdirectories.
>
> /e Edit ACL instead of replacing it.
>
> /c Continue changing ACLs, ignoring errors.
>
> /g user|group:perm Grant specified user or group access permissions. 
>   perm can be:
>
> r Read 
>   c Change (write) 
>   f Full control
>
> /r user Revoke specified user's or group's access permissions.
>
> /p user|group:perm Replace specified user's or group's access 
>   permissions. perm can be:
>
> n None 
>   r Read 
>   c Change (write) 
>   f Full control
>
> /d user|group Deny specified user access.

**Example.**

```
cacls c:\Windows /t /e /g ExampleUSer:r
```

Gives "**ExampleUser**" User **Read only access** to **C/Windows Drive** and **all files / folders**.